# Eloquent ORM Eager-loading Distinct Records in Many to Many Relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

**Background**

I have a List model which belongs to and has many Subscriber. And of course a Subscriber which belongs to and has many List.

**Problem**

I want to eager-load all subscribers from multiple lists. BUT, I am only interested in distinct subscribers, since a subscriber can have and indeed belong to multiple lists.

**My attempt**

I have used the `distinct()` method but this hasn't yielded any joy. And I can also loop through the result set to manually slice out duplicates. Just wondering if there is a way of letting Laravel do the dirty job for me?

**Code**

```
    $lists = Input::get('listsarray');

    $addresses = Addressbook::with(array('subscribers' => function($query)
                    {
                        $query->where('active', '=', 1);
                        // $query->distinct(); //This didn't work
                    }))->whereIn('id', $lists)->get();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Retrieving unique subscribers through join

I'll try my best to explain it using `Lists` instead of `Adressbook`, because I couldn't really understand your model and that may introduce further confusion.

If I understood your comments correctly, you are trying to retrieve all unique subscribers that have associations with lists of `id IN listarray`. In that case, Eager Loading is not the proper way of doing that. Eager loading serves the purpose of pre-loading associations for a model, in order to use them later on. In your case, you are not retrieving `Lists` and their `Subscribers`, but rather the unique `Subscribers` themselves.

```php
$lists = Input::get('listsarray');

$subscribers = Subscriber::join('list_subscriber', 'list_subscriber.subscriber_id', '=', 'subscribers.id')
    ->whereIn('list_subscriber.list_id', $lists)
    ->groupBy('list_subscriber.subscriber_id')
    ->get(array('subscribers.*'));
```

If you also wish to retrieve all lists associated with such subscribers, you can do so:

```php
// Simply include a with('lists') and Eloquent will eager load them
$subscribers = Subscriber::with('lists')
    ->join('list_subscriber', 'list_subscriber.subscriber_id', '=', 'subscribers.id')
    ->whereIn('list_subscriber.list_id', $lists)
    ->groupBy('list_subscriber.subscriber_id')
    ->get(array('subscribers.*'));
```

### Eager Loading

If it's a matter of simply improving performance, you don't need to use distinct, Laravel already does it. Eloquent behaves like this:

1. Fetchs all `lists`.
2. Iterates through `lists` building an array of unique `list_ids`
3. Fetchs all `list_subscribers` using `WHERE list_id IN (X, Y, Z)`
4. Iterates through all `list_subscribers` building an array of unique `subscriber_id`
5. Fetchs all `subscribers` using `WHERE id IN (X, Y, Z)`

Comment: It doesn't seem to have worked that way for me, unfortunately. When I loop through addresses and then loop through their subscribers and var_dump() subscriber ids, for example, I get 4,6,7,11,12,7,12. And a few are repeated. Am I extracting these the wrong way?

Comment: Hmmm, I actually understood you were trying to improve SQL query performance. If so, Eloquent already does it for you. Can you please explain what exactly are you trying to achieve? I can't really understand the real problem (non-technical one) to provide a more precise answer.

Comment: I think you understood the question. Just that the answer doesn't work for me. I have an array of list ids. I want to get all subscribers that belong to those lists. And I don't want duplicated subscribers. Therefore, if someone belongs to two or more lists, they should only appear once in the result set.

Comment: Thanks! Just made two amendments and it worked! pivot table is 'list_subscriber' (following convention in docs) and the 'get' at the end expects an array. So, I modified it to ->get(array('subscribers.*')); and booyah! Thanks, man.

Comment: You are perfectly right (I'm so used to Laravel 3 that these tend to pass). I'll fix these on the answer :)

Comment: I had attempted to edit but it didn't accept my edit until 'peers review the edit'!

Comment: Thank you so much! This problem had troubled me for so many days!!